# How to POST a JSON payload to a @RequestParam in Spring MVC

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm using **Spring Boot** (latest version, **1.3.6**) and I want to create a **REST endpoint** which accepts a bunch of arguments and a JSON object. Something like:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/endpoint \
-d arg1=hello \
-d arg2=world \
-d json='{"name":"john", "lastNane":"doe"}'
```

In the Spring controller I'm currently doing:

```
public SomeResponseObject endpoint(
@RequestParam(value="arg1", required=true) String arg1, 
@RequestParam(value="arg2", required=true) String arg2,
@RequestParam(value="json", required=true) Person person) {

  ...
}
```

The `json` argument doesn't get serialized into a Person object. 
I get a

```
400 error: the parameter json is not present.
```

Obviously, I can make the `json` argument as String and parse the payload inside the controller method, but that kind of defies the point of using Spring MVC.

It all works if I use `@RequestBody`, but then I loose the possibility to POST separate arguments outside the JSON body.

**Is there a way in Spring MVC to "mix" normal POST arguments and JSON objects?**

Comment: I don't think there's a way, and I don't think mixing form-encoded data and json data is a good idea. Decide if you want to accept one or the other.

Comment: Lots of API (Stripe, Plaid, Stormpath) use this approach to logically separate request data (eg. if I'm doing a search, I can put the search criteria in a Json representation and keep pagination data in the form-encoded bit of the form). But I see your point.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes,is possible to send both params and body with a post method:
Example server side:

```
@RequestMapping(value ="test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public Person updatePerson(@RequestParam("arg1") String arg1,
        @RequestParam("arg2") String arg2,
        @RequestBody Person input) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(arg1);
    System.out.println(arg2);
    input.setName("NewName");
    return input;
}
```

and on your client:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8"
     -X POST
     'http://localhost:8080/smartface/api/email/test?arg1=ffdfa&arg2=test2'
     -d '{"name":"me","lastName":"me last"}'
```

Enjoy

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but shows how to do the workaround that the OP specifically stated they didn't want to use.

Answer (score 15):

You can do this by registering a `Converter` from `String` to your parameter type using an auto-wired `ObjectMapper`:

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

@Component
public class PersonConverter implements Converter<String, Person> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public PersonConverter (ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Person convert(String source) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.readValue(source, Person.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: works like a charm also for `@RequestParam` annotated method parameters

Answer (score 0):

you can use RequestEntity.

```
public Person getPerson(RequestEntity<Person> requestEntity) {
    return requestEntity.getBody();
}
```

Answer (score -3):

User:

```
 @Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer userId;
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String email;


    //getter, setter ...
}
```

JSON:

```
{"name":"Sam","email":"sam@gmail.com","password":"1234"}
```

You can use **@RequestBody**:

```
@PostMapping(path="/add")
public String addNewUser (@RequestBody User user) {
    User u = new User(user.getName(),user.getPassword(),user.getEmail());
    userRepository.save(u);
    return "User saved";
}
```